# No logs on a code 500 internal error in Google App Engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, logging

I am getting an inexplicable 500 internal error, when using my generated android client java library in conjunction with Google App Engine. basically, I am getting a 500 internal server error, that never shows up in the logs within Google App Engine Console.

This is my stacktrace:

```
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164): {
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):   "code": 500,
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):   "errors": [
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):     {
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):       "domain": "global",
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):       "message": "Internal Error",
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):       "reason": "internalError"
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):     }
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):   ],
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):   "message": "Internal Error"
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164): }
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at com.andreasrudolph.dreamcloud.SyncDreamsTask.doInBackground(SyncDreamsTask.java:75)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at com.andreasrudolph.dreamcloud.SyncDreamsTask.doInBackground(SyncDreamsTask.java:1)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-18 02:03:44.240: E/(27164):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Is there a way to locate unlogged internal errors in Google App Engine Console?

The error seem to occur when I am attaching a list to my request. As in:

```
SyncStuffRequest syncStuff = service.sync().syncStuff();

syncStuff .set("stuff", an ArrayList of StuffObjects);

syncResponse = syncStuff .execute();
```

Comment: Have you put any log statements in your Service code and checked if they appear in the Console. You could also bump up the Log Level in your logging.properties to DEBUG and see if things appear in the console.

Comment: The big issue is that I get a response code, but the method call is never registered in the